# how can i use proxy with async websockets?

Tags: python, websocket

i have this code (i try to use async websockets with proxy):

```
import asyncio
import websockets
usag  = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"
async def messages_check():
    while True:
            ws_url = f'wss://{...}'
            async with websockets.connect(ws_url, extra_headers=[('user-agent', usag)], http_proxy_host="1.1.1.1", http_proxy_port="1111", proxy_type="http", http_proxy_auth=(login, password)) as server:
                async for msg in server:
                    print(msg)
```

but when I run the program, I don't receive any messages, how can i fix this?

Comment: From the docs: `The client doesn’t support connecting through a HTTP proxy` - https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/limitations.html?highlight=proxy#client. Issue: https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a package to do that: https://github.com/racinette/websockets_proxy

In the README there is also code for proxy checker (both client and server) for you to make sure it works correctly.